# Does crypto++ or openssl support ISO/IEC 9796-2 Digital Signature scheme with message recovery?

Tags: c++, openssl

I need to verify and recover message from signature that was created with the following params.
Digital Signature/Verification scheme  ISO/IEC 9796-2,  hash SHA1.
Can I use  crypto++ or openssl for verification and recovery operation of that kind of signature?

Comment: I'm not sure if it confirms to the ISO/IEC 9796-2 standard but their is verification and recovery from a signed SHA1 hash [here][1] on their wiki. Also check cryptlib.h and pubkey.h


  [1]: http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes#RSA_Probabilistic_Signature_Scheme_with_Recovery